# How can I remove these blue lines without losing the color?

Tags: patterns, image-editing

[image]I need to learn how to remove these blue lines without changing anything else.

Comment: If you'd ask me, it'd be *way* faster to recreate the pattern from scratch in Illustrator that it'd be to try and edit out the raster in a photo editing program.

Answer (score 2):

Too much work to remove the line pattern. Make a new yourself.

It seems to be a big piece of chipwood with half transparent white overlay pattern. That pattern is easy to do in Illustrator (measurements only approximate)

[image]

- have a triangle, say 6 degrees angle in the sharpest corner, one long side is horizontal, grey fill, no stroke
- rotate the triangle 0,5 degrees
- rotate the triangle making 11 more copies in 7,5 degrees steps
- align all 12 triangles down & left to get the sharp corners to the same point
- copy twice with reflect to have a fan that covers full 360 degrees
- scale horizontally to smaller size to have elliptical pattern
- change the fill color to white
- add a clipping mask to have rectangular shape
- copy to photoshop to insert it over a photo of chipwood

I hadn't a good photo, so I used a flat color fill.

Photoshop is in theory not necessary at all for this job, but coloring is there easier.

**Addendum: If you want to stay in Photoshop and want something fast, then:**

- select all
- goto Filter > Blur > Radial Blur > Zoom, good quality, radius=60px
- fix (=clone) the middle area manually, if needed.
- add some grainy texture, if needed